# Visual C++ - qSort with Strings

Tags: c++

Yes, I want to use the qsort() function with  two strings, most likely those will be tested as character arrays. When I run it,I get an unhandled exception in qsort.c at the line(151):

```
    if (__COMPARE(context, lo, mid) > 0) {
        swap(lo, mid, width);
    }
```

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

struct SaleSlip{
    char name[20];
    int ProdID;
    double value;
};
int compare(void const *a, void const *b);
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, SaleSlip& sales);

int main(){
    SaleSlip sales[17] = {
        {"Eric",   1, 200000.00},
        {"Sookie", 2,    200.00},
        {"Sookie", 4,    200.50},
        {"Bill",   3,   5000.00},
        {"Bill",   5,   7500.00},
        {"Tara",   4,    350.50},
        {"Eric",   2,    200.00},
        {"Tara",   2,    200.00},
        {"Tara",   4,    350.50},
        {"Bill",   5,   2500.00},
        {"Sookie", 1,  50000.00},
        {"Sookie", 2,    200.00},
        {"Eric",   5,  10000.00},
        {"Tara",   2,    200.00},
        {"Tara",   4,    150.50},
        {"Bill",   5,   1000.00},
        {"Sookie", 4,    400.50}        
    };
    cout << "The array before sorting is: " << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
        cout << sales[i];
    qsort(sales[0].name, 17, (sizeof(sales)/sizeof(char*)), compare);
    cout << "The array after sorting is: ";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, SaleSlip& sales){
    out << setiosflags(ios::left | ios::fixed) << setw(7) << sales.name << setw(3) << sales.ProdID 
        << setprecision(2) << sales.value << endl;
    return out;
}

int compare(void const *a, void const *b) { 
    return strcmp(*(const char **)a, *(const char **)b);
}
```

I am testing in compare properly? Am I calling qsort properly?

Comment: Suggestion: use `std::string` and `std::sort`.

Comment: No, you are not calling `qsort` properly.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want your compare function to take SaleSlip pointers as the argument.  In the compare function do strcmp(a->name,b->name).  Of course your arguments to qsort will change to become SaleSlip structs.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing wrong is:

I. You pass in 17 as both the element size and the element count to `qsort()`. That's wrong, the 2nd argument is the number of elements in the array, the 3rd one is the size of one individual element.

II. you want to sort the array, but you don't pass in the address of its first element, but a pointer to the `name` member of the first element. Take this and the incorrect element size, and from now on, all the pointers `qsort()` operates on are quite arbitrary, and using them is not any good. What you could do is:

I. Write a proper comparator function and don't try to include nasty tricks:

```
qsort(sales, sizeof(sales) / sizeof(sales[0]), sizeof(sales[0]), comp);

int comp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    // the two lines below are the aesthetic reason
    // for NOT using qsort() in C++. The ugly cast is not needed in C.

    const SaleSlip *s1 = static_cast<const SaleSlip *>(a);
    const SaleSlip *s2 = static_cast<const SaleSlip *>(b);

    return strcmp(s1->name, s2->name);
}
```

II. Or, even better: use `std::sort`, `std::string` and define `SaleSlip::operator <`:

```
class SaleSlip {
    bool operator <(const SaleSlip &that) {
        return this->name < that.name;
    }
};

std::sort(sales, sales + sizeof(sales) / sizeof(sales[0]));
```

Bonus: don't use hard-coded sizes and types. `17` is dangerous, `sizeof(array) / sizeof(SaleSlip)` is better but still not perfect, `sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])` is entirely safe, no matter what you do with the base type and the element count of the array.

Comment: @Yakk Yeah, I'm used to C... After all, if code needs typecasting, it looks suspicious :)

Comment: Appreciated H2CO3, especially for dealing with my stubbornness and explaining it.

Comment: @user2592862 When I saw `qsort(sales[0].name`, I **instantly** knew what was wrong, I didn't even read the question fully :P Advice: think twice before compiling your code. Consider the semantics, why and how certain functions accomplish their task. I'm sure if you had kept thinking a bit about this, it would have sooner or later come to your mind that the use of `qsort()` was wrong.

Comment: I knew it was I had no idea how, I had been looking at the reference all morning and must've just missed it. I usually try to break them down to understand them, but I had stayed up until 4am trying (not a good idea on my part). But, thanks for the advice and helpfulness.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::sort` : `qsort` is harder to use in almost every case, and less efficient.

First, write a `order` function:
    struct SaleSlip{
      char name[20];
      int ProdID;
      double value;
    };
    bool order( SaleSlip const& lhs, SaleSlip const& rhs ) {
      return strncmp(lhs.name, rhs.name, sizeof(lhs.name))<0;
    }
then feed this to `std::sort`:

```
std::sort( &sales[0], &sales[sizeof(sales)/sizeof(sales[0])], order );
```

and your are done.

In C++11, that line is better:

```
std::sort( std::begin(sales), std::end(sales), order );
```

You can also replace `name` with a `std::string` rather than work with a fixed sized buffer, but I understand there are reasons to work with raw `char` buffers.  If you do so, simply change `order` to return `lhs.name < rhs.name`.

The problems in your original code, above and beyond the choice to use `qsort`, is that the blocks of memory you are sorting are `SaleSlip` objects, not `char*` objects.  First, fix your `compare` function (and give it a better name):

```
int compare_pvoid_SaleSlips(void const *a, void const *b) { 
  SalesSlip const* lhs = static_cast<SalesSlip const*>(a);
  SalesSlip const* rhs = static_cast<SalesSlip const*>(b);
  return strncmp(lhs->name, rhs->name, sizeof(lhs->name)/sizeof(lhs->name[0]));
}
```

Next, fix your call to `qsort`:

```
qsort(&sales[0], 17, (sizeof(sales)/sizeof(sales[0])), compare_pvoid_SaleSlips);
```

which should work.  However, following this method will be slower, more error prone, more brittle, and in every way worse in a C++ program than the `std::sort` solution.

Answer (score 0):

Three problems:

- The first argument should just be `sales` - the array you want to sort.
- The size argument should be `sizeof(SaleSlip)` - the size of each element.
- The comparison is doing something very strange. To get a pointer to the name, you want `static_cast<const SaleSlip*>(a)->name` (or `(const char*)a` if you like to live dangerously).

These problems can be avoided by using the C++ `std::sort` function (and `std::string` for the string), which is type-safe and (often) more efficient than `qsort`. Then you simply do

```
std::sort(std::begin(sales), std::end(sales), 
    [](SaleSlip const & a, SaleSlip const & b) {return a.name < b.name;});
```